# be out the window

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> - All right, here's the deal. Sheldon is gone, so the tree decorating rules **are out the window**.
>     Yeah, which means we don't have to use his ridiculous ornament-spacing template.

what does it mean **are out the window** ?

Comment: Please read [*Why you should cite your source*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on meta and follow that guidance in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

"[Out of the window](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+window)" is an idiomatic expression that means something is no longer possible, or no longer an option.

In your example - which I recognise is from *The Big Bang Theory*, it means that as Sheldon is not with them to enforce his arbitrary rules, they do not need to follow any rules.

A similar idiomatic expression is "[off the table](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+table)".

Comment: ***Snap!!!***  :)

Comment: Casual/informal for 'out **of** the window'.

Answer (score 0):

In the cited usage, ***the window*** is just an idiomatic "flourish" - it could just as well have stopped at *tree decorating rules are **out***, where ***out*** is effectively ***no longer relevant, dismissed from consideration***.

In the *exact* context, we can probably assume that "no longer relevant" sense more precisely implies *We no longer have to concern ourselves with sticking to those rules* (presumably because Sheldon is gone, and only ***he*** was particularly concerned that those rules should be respected).

It may be worth noting the very closely related idiomatic usage ***off the table*** - which also has that "no longer relevant" sense, but with the specific implication that those rules are ***no longer subject to negotiation*** (the metaphoric allusion is to a "negotiating table", where participants agree what rules to observe).